# Extract additional method Info from Dll

Tags: c#, dll

In my solution i have dll which contains methods in below format

```
    [TestMethod]
    [TestProperty("Priority", "P0")]
    [TestProperty("Owner", "vbnmg")]
    [TestProperty("Title", "Verify the log accessible")]
    [TestProperty("ID", "1")]
    public void LogAccesiblityTest()
    {
    //Test Code
    }
```

Some method have different priority,Owner,ID & Title

By Providing the dll  name & serach criteria (priority,Owner,ID & Title), can i get the methods name which are in given priority groupr or owner group etc.

I have the code through which i am getting the detail information of method names & parameres used, but i am not getting how to get the info from test property.

Can Someone please suggest how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're just looking for [`MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.getcustomattributes.aspx). Given your format, I'd probably write something like this:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetProperties(MethodInfo method)
{
    return method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestPropertyAttribute), false)
                 .Cast<TestProperty>()
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
}
```

(That's assuming the `TestPropertyAttribute` *has* `Key` and `Value` properties, of course.)

To just detect the *presence* of an attribute (which you might want for  `TestMethodAttribute`) you can use [`MemberInfo.IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.isdefined.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the `MethodInfo` objects (because you said you already have the code to get the information), you can call [`MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.getcustomattributes.aspx) to get those attributes. It also has an overload where you can pass the type of the attribute you look for. You then just need to cast the results and inspect their properties.